# Извлечь данные из массива при выборе радиокнопки

Tags: php, javascript, html

Есть массив:

```
$arr = [
   ['id'=>101, 'note'=>'Содержание_1'],
   ['id'=>108, 'note'=>'Содержание_2'],
   ['id'=>258, 'note'=>'Содержание_3']
];
```

На странице php генерируются радиокнопки значение которых равно элементу 'id' из массива $arr.

Вот примерный код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.id').click(function(){
        $('.note').html($(this).val());
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$arr = array(
    array('id'=>101, 'note'=>'Содержание_1'),
    array('id'=>108, 'note'=>'Содержание_2'),
    array('id'=>258, 'note'=>'Содержание_3')
);
?>
<input class="id" name="id" type="radio" value="<?=$arr[0]['id']?>" />punkt 1
<input class="id" name="id" type="radio" value="<?=$arr[1]['id']?>" />punkt 2
<input class="id" name="id" type="radio" value="<?=$arr[2]['id']?>" />punkt 3
<div class="note"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Сейчас у меня при выборе радиокнопки в div class="note" попадает значение 'id'.

Можно ли с помощью javascript извлечь значение 'note' из массива $arr, у которого 'id' равно значению выбранной радиокнопки и вывести в div class="note"

Comment: По моему из массива php не получиться извлечь с помощью javascript, или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Народ может кто нибудь помочь, очень нужно решить

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать таким образом, но все данные будут видны в DOM'e

```
<input class="id" name="id" type="radio" value="<?=$arr[0]['id']?>" 
      data-array="<?=$arr[0]['note']?>"/>punkt 1

<script>
$(function(){
    $('.id').click(function(){
        $('.note').html($(this).attr('data-array'));
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: То что будет видны в DOM'e как то не хорошо, т.е. это плохо

Comment: @Xfirab А чем это плохо, если не секрет?

Comment: @rjhdby  не я хотел спросить, т.е. "Это хорошо или нет ? "
А так решение lyhoshva вполне подошло

Comment: @Xfirab data-атрибуты предназначены для использования через JS. Вообще это нормально просто все зависти от данных которые там находятся.

Comment: @lyhoshva  еще такой момент, сейчас у меню в элемент 'note' попало значение 'a"88" Содержание_1', и после буквы 'а' ничего не выходит. Здесь по моему двойные кавычки мешают. Как-то можно их экранировать?

Comment: @Xfirab попробуйте \"

Comment: @lyhoshva уже пробовал, не получается ((  После кавычки все пропадает. Еще можете что нибудь посоветовать?

Comment: Все решил, двойные кавычки заменил на  спецкод html '&#34;'. Спасибо всем кто помог.

Answer (score 1):

Вы не сможете извлечь данные из php-массива по той простой причине, что этот массив существует только в момент исполнения php-скрипта. Как только скрипт отработал и отдал отрендеренную страницу веб-серверу для передачи клиентскому браузеру - массив исчезает. (не будем сейчас рассматривать кеширования и сессии, так как по сути те-же яйца, только в профиль)

Решений тут ровно два:

1. Отдавать эти данные на клиент. Либо как атрибуты DOM, либо как массив JS.
2. При выборе радиокнопки делать запрос к бэкенду.

Comment: @PavelMayorov это вы к чему, извините?

Comment: @PavelMayorov я тоже не понял

Comment: @rjhdby это я к вашему недавнему голосу за закрытие спама

Answer (score 0):

А в чем проблема при получении `id` сделать вызов `php` скрипта через `ajax`, передать в запросе `id` и получить соответствующее значение `note`?

В данном случае я вижу только такое решение, при условии, что вы не хотите выводить значение `note` на страницу.

Другое решение предложил [@lyhoshva](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/220134/lyhoshva) - использовать `data-class`, также возможно выводить значение `note` в `input type="hidden"`